# Как лучше прописать условие if

Tags: python

Есть код:

```
# < Запрос из таблицы items новостей для проверки.
cursor.execute('SELECT  `item_link` FROM `items` WHERE 1')
item_link = cursor.fetchall()

# < Вызов всех функций.
def call_all_func(resources):
    # < Цикл для перебора из кортежа.
    for resource in resources:
        resource_name = resource[1]
        resource_link = resource[2]
        resource_url = resource[3]
        link_rule = resource[4]
        title_rule = resource[5]
        datetime_rule = resource[6]
        datetime1_rule = resource[7]
        text_rule = resource[8]
        text1_rule = resource[9]
        print(resource_name)
        resource_domain=resource_link
        # < Разбиваю данные из кортежа в массив.
        links_rule = link_rule.split(',')
        title_rule = title_rule.split(',')
        datetime_rule = datetime_rule.split(',')
        datetime1_rule = datetime1_rule.split(',')
        text_rule = text_rule.split(',')
        text1_rule = text1_rule.split(',')
        resource_page = get_html(resource_url)
        resource_links = get_resource_links(resource_page,links_rule,resource_domain)
        print('кол-во ссылок: '+str(len(resource_links)))

        # < Цикл для вызова функции.
        for resource_link in resource_links:
            item_page = get_html(resource_link)
            item_title = get_item_title(item_page,title_rule)
            item_datetime = get_item_datetime(item_page,datetime_rule,datetime1_rule)
            item_text_content = get_text_content(item_page,text_rule,text1_rule)

            # < Запись новостей в БД.

            # sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            # cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
            # print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')

call_all_func(resources)
```

Я бы хотел так.Пример: Вот допустим я создам такое условие `if resource_id != items_link`то тогда делай `insert` новостей.

```
sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
            cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
            print('Запись в базу данных успешно завершена!')
```

Суть того что мне нужно такова:Мне нужно чтобы этот кусок кода не добавлял повторяющиеся новости в БД.Чтобы мой кусок кода не добавлял повторяющиеся новости.Мне нужно одну новость из resource_link проверять в запросе item_links.После проверки если этой новости нету то тогда новость стоит добавлять.Вот такое мне нужно условие,а как его реализовать,я не знаю.

Comment: Я прочитал вопрос и не понял в чем он заключается.

Comment: Напишите минимальный пример что вы хотите сделать и у вас не выходит

Comment: Хорошо,сейчас напишу

Comment: @Эникейщик  я дополнил вопрос

Comment: @EugeneDennis дополнил вопрос

Comment: Мне лично понятнее не стало. Кстати, зачем условие `WHERE 1` в первом запросе?

Comment: Я взял этот с запрос с phpmyadmin

Comment: @V-Mor `WHERE 1 ` это каноническая запись запроса с пустым `where clause`, так что, все верно.

Comment: @V-Mor,Суть того что мне нужно такова:Мне нужно чтобы этот кусок кода не добавлял повторяющиеся новости в БД.Чтобы мой кусок кода не добавлял повторяющиеся новости.Мне нужно одну новость из `resource_link` проверять в запросе `item_links`.После проверки если этой новости нету то тогда новость стоит добавлять.Вот такое мне нужно условие,а как его реализовать,я не знаю.Надеюсь теперь вы поняли.И сможете мне помочь

Comment: @Raharasomaha, а что не так с использованием `UNIQUE KEY` в SQL таблице и обработкой соответствующего исключения - вы уже задавали этот вопрос раньше?

Comment: Такой вариант мне подходит. Т.к  задача именно стоит чтобы решение было с условием if

Comment: @MaxU вот у меня же есть переменная `resource_link` там хранятся новости.Как с условием  можно сделать такую проверку.Новостей в БД

Comment: ["Quae sunt Caesaris Caesari et quae sunt Dei Deo"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%8E_%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE) - пусть проверкой уникальности значения поля занимается БД!

Comment: ........................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прописал условие так:

```
cursor.execute('SELECT `item_link` FROM `items` WHERE `item_link` = "'+resource_link+'"')
                item_link = cursor.fetchall()

                # < Запись новостей в БД.
                if len(item_link) == 0:
                    sql = "insert into items (`item_link`,`item_title`,`item_datetime`,`item_text_content`) values (%s,%s,%s,%s)"
                    cursor.execute(sql,(str(resource_link),str(item_title),str(item_datetime),str(item_text_content)))
                    print('Запись новостей успешно произведена!')
                else: print('Пропуск новости')
```

Answer (score 0):

Для сравнения можно использовать для поиска повторяющийся новости

```
news = cursor.execute('SELECT `item_link` FROM `items` WHERE `item_links` = "сылка на новость котрую вы проверяете ")
```

После этого запроса мы получаем либо пустую переменную либо переменную с чем-то, а в `if` просто проверяем на пустоту и если пустая то записываем

Comment: Благодарю за внимание.Но это не работает.

Comment: какие возникают ошибки?

Comment: Потому что при экзекюте этого ссылку на новость оно будет считаться как булеан со значением тру

Comment: Вот у меня есть база данных,а вот этой базе данных есть таблицы для новостей.В этой таблице есть столбец с ссылкой,заголовком,датой и контентом новости.И вот чтобы мой код не добавлял лишний раз одинаковые новости.
Мне нужно взять одну новость из resource_link и проверить это в запросе item_links с помощью условия if

Comment: странно когда я делал подобную схему для проверки id все было нормально

Comment: Теперь уже видимо не так.